# How to add line breaks within a cell on merged rows in R studio?

Tags: r, merge, concatenation, cell

I would like to merge the rows into 1 single cell. So there should be 1 row which has all data together concatenated. Then, I would need the text title "Top coins today!" above it, appearing once only.

I have been able to merge the rows into 1 singular cell using str_c function with below code.

```
xyz_1 <- paste0('Top performing coins in the last 24 hrs!', 
            paste(df2$id, " - ",  
            df2$price_change_percentage_24h) %>% 
     str_c(collapse = '\n'), sep="\n")
```

This has worked. However, I do not know how to create a line break between "Top performing coins" and the data. It needs to be so like in the attached image. Basically, I need to create a line break in a cell.

The dataframe DPUT is below if required.

```
structure(list(id = c("xdai-stake", "hegic", "keep-network"), 
    price_change_percentage_24h = c(26.96, 26.62, 23.93)), row.names = c(43L, 36L, 38L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired output should look like this - https://ibb.co/tJRTdfr. This is how it should appear and structured.

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using the tibble function.

```
df2 <- tibble(top3subset)

xyz_1 <- paste0('Top performing coins in the last 24 hrs!', "
            ", 
            paste(df2$id, " - ",  
                  df2$price_change_percentage_24h) %>% 
              str_c(collapse = '\n'), sep="\n")
```

This solution was the closest I got to the desired output. Frankly, it sufficed.